# can't output from my checkedlistbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, tchecklistbox

I'm just learning vb and have some problems in outputting specific checked items in my text box. I've tried a lot of ways but still can't get the right one, maybe I forgot something?

```
    Private Sub submitBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles submitBtn.Click
    Dim output As String
    Dim listOfProd As String
    listOfProd = ""


    output = "Selected Region: " + destination.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Seleted Place: " +
        places.SelectedItem + Environment.NewLine + "Accomodation: " +
        accomodation.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Products Selected: " + Environment.NewLine

    For i As Integer = 0 To products.Items.Count
        If products.Items(i) Is products.CheckedItems Then
            listOfProd = listOfProd + products.Items(i)

        End If
    Next

    output = output + listOfProd

    outputHere.Text = output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping through and determining which check box list items are checked, just use the `CheckedItems` collection, like this:

```
' Loop through only the items that are checked 
For Each itemChecked In products.CheckedItems
    ' Get the text of the selected item and append it to the output string
    listOfProd = listOfProd + itemChecked.ToString()
Next
```